# Removing "Show images"

Tags: windows-7, email, lotus-notes

I am using IBM Lotus Noted and I need very frequently to click on "Show images" to get images downloaded.

Any possibility to make this selection as default? So, images are downloaded automatically whenever I am getting an Email, and without a need to click every time on "Show images"?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [online help](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Display_):

1. Click **File > Preferences**
2. Click the plus sign beside **Mail**, and then click **Internet**.
3. Clear the **To ensure privacy, do not show remote images without my permission** check box to automatically display remote images in Internet mail you receive.

Comment: Good answer. Can I make this selective. I mean that, it is happening for those Email addresses I already selected to Download and not for all?

Comment: One setting to rule them all....